# Friedman test unreplicated complete block design error

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics

I'm having trouble running a Friedman test over my data.
I'm trying to run a Friedman test using this command:

```
friedman.test(mean ~ isi | expId, data=monoSum)
```

On the following database (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ox0y1b4gwld0ai/monoSum.csv):

```
> monoSum
   expId isi  N       mean
1  m80B1   1 10 100.000000
2  m80B1   2 10  73.999819
3  m80B1   3 10  45.219362
4  m80B1   4 10 116.566174        
.   .     .   .          .
18 m80L2   2 10  82.945491
19 m80L2   3 10  57.675480
20 m80L2   4 10 207.169277
.    .     .  .   .      .
25 m80M2   1 10 100.000000
26 m80M2   2 10  49.752687
27 m80M2   3 10  19.042592
28 m80M2   4 10 150.411035
```

It gives me back the error:

```
Error in friedman.test.default(c(100, 73.9998193095267, 45.2193621626293,  : 
not an unreplicated complete block design
```

I figure it gives the error because, when `monoSum$isi==1` the value of mean is always 100. Is this correct?

However, `monoSum$isi==1` is alway 100 because it is the control group on which all the other `monoSum$isi` groups are normalized. I can not assume a normal distribution, so I cannot run a rmANOVA…
Is there a way to run a friedman test on this data or am I missing a very essential point here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I also tried to perform the analysis on the continuous values of the means in stead of the normalized values… Same error :(

Comment: I found this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59768686/18143306

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't get an error if I run your dataset:

```
   Friedman rank sum test

   data:  mean and isi and expId
   Friedman chi-squared = 17.9143, df = 3, p-value = 0.0004581
```

However, you have to make sure that `expId` and  `isi` are coded as factors. Run these commands:

```
    monoSum$expID$<-factor(monoSum$expID)
    monoSum$isi$<-factor(monoSum$isi)
```

Then run the test again. This has worked for me with a similar problem.

Comment: I restarted R and it now runs smoothly here too… Even without coding as factors… Unbelievable this had me going for almost over a week :') Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 6):

I know this is pretty old but for future generations (see also: me when I forget and google this again):

You can determine what the missing values are in your dataframe by running `table(groups, blocks)` or in the case of this question `table(monoSum$isi, monoSum$expID)`.  This will return a table of 0s and 1s.  This missing records are in the the cells with 0s.

I ran into this problem after trying to remove the blocks that had incomplete results; taking a subset of the data did not remove the blocks for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I would mention I found this post because I was getting a similar error message. The above suggestions did not solve it. Strangely, I had to sort my dataframe so that block by block the groups appeared in order (i.e. I could not have the following:
Block 1     A
Block 1     B
Block 2     B
Block 2     A

It has to appear as A, B, A, B)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same cryptic error message in R, though in my case it was resolved when I applied the 'as.matrix' function to what was originally a dataframe for the CSV file I imported in using the read.csv() function.

I also had a missing data point in my original data set, and I found that when my data was transformed into a matrix for the friedman.test() call, the entire row containing the missing data point was omitted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Using the function as.matrix() to transform my dataframe is the magic that got the function to run for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error too with my dataset.
It turns out that the function `friedman.test()` accepts *data frames* (fx those created by `data.frame()` ) but not *tibbles* (those created by dplyr and other modern tools). The solution for me was to convert my dataset to a dataframe first.

```
D_fri <- D_all %>% dplyr::select(FrustrationEpisode, Condition, Participant)
D_fri <- as.data.frame(D_fri)
str(D_fri) # confirm the object should now be a 'data.frame'
friedman.test(FrustrationEpisode ~ Condition | Participant, D_fri)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. Fixed mine by removing the NAs.

```
# My data (called layers) looks like:
| resp.no | av.l.all | av.baseem | av.base |
| 1       | 1.5      | 1.3       | 2.3     |
| 2       | 1.4      | 3.2       | 1.4     |
| 3       | 2.5      | 2.8       | 2.9     |
...
| 1088    | 3.6      | 1.1       | 3.3     |

# Remove NAs
layers1 <- na.omit(layers)

# Re-organise data so the scores are stacked, and a column added with the original column name as a factor
layers2 <- layers1 %>%
  gather(key = "layertype", value = "score", av.l.all, av.baseem, av.base) %>%
  convert_as_factor(resp.no, layertype)

# Data now looks like this
| resp.no | layertype | score  | 
| 1       | av.l.all  | 1.5    | 
| 1       | av.baseem | 1.3    | 
| 1       | av.base   | 2.3    | 
| 2       | av.l.all  | 1.4    | 
...
| 1088    | av.base   | 3.3    | 

# Then do Friedman test
friedman.test(score ~ layertype | resp.no, data = layers2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share what my problem was. My ID factor did not have correct levels after doing pivot_longer(). Because of this, the same error was given. I made sure the correct level and it worked by the following:as.factor(as.character(df$ID))

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33290240)

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread with new information. I ran into a similar problem after removing `NA`s. My group and block were factors before the `NA` removal. However, after removing `NA`s, the factors retained the levels before the removal even though some levels were no longer in the data!

Running the `friedman.test()` with the `as.matrix()` trick (e.g., `friedman.test(a ~ b | c, as.matrix(df))`) was fine but running `frdAllPairsExactTest()` or `friedman_effsize()` would throw the **not an unreplicated complete block design** error. I ended up **re-factoring** the group and block (i.e., dropping the levels that were no longer in the data, `df$block <- factor(df$block)`) to make things work. After the re-factor, I did not need the `as.matrix()` trick, either.